# Approved Request Sent notification appearing permanently on my iPhone screen and not allowing any use of the phone, despite clicking OK

Tags: ios, icloud, two-factor-authentication

After updating my iPhone to the latest iOS version a couple of weeks ago, every time I go to use my iPhone I have 2 consecutive notifications flash up on my screen re iCloud "approve your device".

Normally I can just tap OK through each and everything is back to normal. Whilst it was on Flight Mode today, it happened again, except this time the second message would not disappear and is now stuck on the screen and I can’t do anything with the phone. The message specifically states:

> Approval Request Sent
>
> To continue using iCloud on this iPhone, approve it from one of your
>   other devices using iCloud or enter your iCloud Security Code
>
> OK
>
> Please advise by return email

When I try to access the iCloud site, it's requesting I enter a Two Factor Authentication 6 digit pass code, but i guess its sending that to my phone, which I can’t access.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Did you restart your phone already, and disabled flight mode? Is the message still stuck done? Which devices did you set for 2FA? Do you have your iCloud Security Code ready?

Comment: Hello and thanks. I wasn't shutting it down properly (not using both button - i am hopeless with IT), and after doing that correctly and disabling flight mode, i was able to get it working and receive the iCloud security code. I hope all's good now, though i haven't been prompted to do anything relating to the notifications i was receiving, ye have not received any since. Thanks again.

Comment: Just noticed i am still receiving the notifications. What do i have to do to make them stop?

Comment: Approve it from another device or enter your security code on the device.

Comment: This needs to be closed in all likelihood as unclear / too broad. Anyone offering you advice other than contacting support could make things worse. You basically need to log into iCloud.com and determine how many trusted devices are valid before wiping this phone. We can’t know what apple support does about why you didn’t approve the prompts and what the servers want and balance that with whatever resolution you want.